# How to approach set word problems like the one below?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

### Set word-problem

> There are $30$ Widgets, and every Widget is a Woodle. There are $20$
>   Wopets, half of which are Woodles. No Wopet is a Widget. Half of all
>   Woodles are Widgets.
>
> How many Woodles are neither Widgets or Wopets?

---

### How I tried solving

Let

- $W_d = \text{\{set of all Wi}$$\boxed{d} \text{gets\}}$
- $W_o = \text{\{set of all Wo}$$\boxed{o} \text{dles\}}$
- $W_p = \text{\{set of all Wo}$$\boxed{p} \text{ets\}}$

Given,

1. $n(W_d)=30$
2. $n(W_p)=20$
3. $W_d \subset W_o$
4. $W_p \cap W_d = \emptyset$
5. $\frac{n(W_o)}{2}=n(W_d)$
6. $n(W_o \cap W_p)=10$

> First of all, what is the **total number of elements in set $W_o$**?

According to given #5,

$\frac{n(W_o)}{2}=n(W_d) \\ \frac{n(W_o)}{2}=30 \\ n(W_o)=2 \times 30 \\ \therefore \boxed{n(W_o)=60}$

> How many members of set $W_o$ *are* Widgets and Wopet?

According to givens #5 and #6,

$W_o$ has $30\times W_d$s and $10\times W_p$s.

> So the number of **other** things in $W_o$ must be the **total number of elements** in the set *minus* **the number of Widgets and Wopets** in it.

$$60-(30+10) \\ =60-40 \\=\boxed{20}$$

$$W_o= \text{\{} 30 \times W_d \text{,} \\10 \times W_p \text{,} \\ 20 \times \text{Others} \text{\}}$$

---

### I know, it's not standard

I've just started learning about sets and I find the concepts fascinating. But I feel uncomfortable solving word problems. Not because I don't understand, but because I don't know how to organise my ideas into a standard solution.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's unorganised and too mathy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on a math discussion site, it can never be too "mathy".  You could just, do:

$|W_o|=2|W_d|\therefore |W_o\setminus (W_d\cap W_o)|=|W_d|\\|W_o\cap W_p|={1\over2}|W_p|\land|W_p\cap W_d|=0\therefore |W_o\setminus (W_o\cap W_p)\cup W_d)|=|W_o|-|W_d|-{1\over 2}|W_p|\\|W_o|-|W_d|-{1\over 2}|W_p|=2|W_d|-|W_d|-{1\over 2}|W_p|=2(30)-30-10 =60-30-10=30-10=\boxed{20}\\ \text {if you knew |X| was the cardinality of X, $\land$ is a logical AND, and $\setminus$ was for set difference.}$

Comment: So organised. Now, this is what I call mathy! Compared to your solution, my one is so straightforward and bland.

Comment: I, actually forgot parentheses in one place, so not really organised. It's only because I have learned ( or researched) how to put things into mathematical language ( and then translated that into MathJax), that I could make it more mathematical. I also know, PARI/GP uses setminus for set difference ( as does the symbol $\setminus$. fixed the typo now.

Comment: My solution's use of notation wasn't completely correct in many places. That's why, it's too necessarily mathy. Math when used correctly is a beauty to behold, even if excessive (in fact, more so then).